# What if a subscriber to an Observable needs to trigger OnNext()?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an Observable that is keeping track of a state, kind of like a state machine.

I have a subscriber to the Observable that detects when things are in a particular state, and it needs to push things into a new state, effectively calling OnNext() on the Observable!

This violates the Rx principle of only having one OnNext() in-flight at a time!  Any good ways around this? Like scheduling the OnNext() to occur directly after the current one is done propogating?

Answer (score 2):

In Control Systems Theory, this type of system is a control loop having feedback. It resists conventional analysis because the input of the system depends on the output - which may be a continuous function.

It is possible to do the same with Observables (which are essentially a discrete stream of values), - i.e., declaratively express a control system. C# semantics make the implementation not very elegant, though. (F# has the option of recursive bindings).

First we need to define a closure for writing the feedback loop.

```
    public delegate IObservable<T> Feedback<T>(IObservable<T> feedback, out IObservable<T> output);
    public static IObservable<T> FeedbackSystem<T>(Feedback<T> closure)
    {
        IObservable<T> source = Observable.Empty<T>(), output;
        source = closure(Observable.Defer(() => source), out output);
        return output;
    }
```

Using the above, here is an example implementation of a speed governer which accelerates upto 100, and maintains the speed below it, even when random errors are introduced into the speed.

```
    var system =
    FeedbackSystem((IObservable<double> acceleration, out IObservable<double> velocity) =>
    {
        //Time axis: moves forward every 0.1s
        double t = 0.1; var timeaxis = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(t));

        velocity = acceleration.Sample(timeaxis)                //move in time
                               .Scan((u, a) => u + a * t)   //u' = u + at
                               .Select(u => u + new Random().Next(10))  //some variations in speed
                               .Publish().RefCount();                   //avoid recalculation

        //negative feedback
        var feedback = velocity.Select(u => 0.5 * (100 - u));

        return feedback.Select(a => Math.Min(a, 15.0))  //new limited acceleration
                       .StartWith(0);                   //initial value          
    });

    system.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

A case of Statemachines would be possible by making the input dependent on the output in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, I'd say you probably "want to do something else" - that is, have another injection point into the observable, like the containing class, etc. has a method `PushState(...)`

At any rate, you *can* retain "I'll tell you what's next" semantics either by backing the `IObservable` with a `Subject<T>` or by specifying your injection route during creation with `Observable.Create`

(although `Subject<T>` is looked down upon by many folks, due to it's "non-purity")